# Dynamically Populate Drop down List In Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. I have two Dropdown Lists in Jsp.One for country and Other for State. As soon as i select country from list State list should be populated with respective lists.

My ajax Program:

```
 $("select#country").change(function() {
    var val=$("#country").val();
    alert(val);
    $.ajax({
    url : 'getstates',
    method : 'get',
    contentType: 'application/json',
     data :{
              country : val
            },

      success: function (data) {
      alert("Success Response"+ data);

      },

       error :function()
       {
               alert("error");
        }          

       });
```

My Controller Program:

```
 public @ResponseBody HashMap<String, String> 
    showstates(@RequestParam(required = false, value =      "") 
    String country,@Valid    @ModelAttribute("employee")Login employee, 
    BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {  
    HashMap<String,String>  statelist = new HashMap<String,String>();
    List<States> statelist = new ArrayList<States>();
    if (country.equals("UnitedStates")) {
    statelist.put("Al","Alaska");
    statelist.put("Tl","Texas");
    } else if (country.equals("India")) {
    statelist.put("Mh","Maharashtra");
    statelist.put("WB","West Bengal");
    statelist.put("KR","Karnataka");
    statelist.put("AP","Andhra Pradesh");
    statelist.put("TN","Tamil Nadu");
    } 
    return statelist;
    }
```

I am not getting the response from controller. How to access the hasmap in jsp. Please Help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your method like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getstates", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody HashMap<String, String>  showstates(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "") 
    String country,@Valid    @ModelAttribute("employee")Login employee, 
    BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {  
    HashMap<String,String>  stateMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    //put your logic to add state on basis of country

    return stateMap;
    }
```

Then on JSP you can simply iterate this map,like below.

```
<c:forEach items="${state.stateMap}" var="data" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <td>${data.value}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using Spring form. How to access Hashmap in jsp. And i am using jquery not jstl.

Comment: $.ajax({
         url : 'getstates',
               method : 'get',
               ContentType : 'json',
               data : {
                 country : val
               },
               success : function(response) {
                alert("hi");
                 var options = '';
                 if (response != null) {
                   $(response).each(function(index, value) {
                     
                     options = options + '<option>' + value       '</option>';
                   });
                   $('#states').html(options);

Comment: Above is my Jquery function to access Hashmap. I am not able to access state names in list. Sorry i could not edit the code properly. Can you please help me to access the State Names?? Thanks in advance

Comment: are you getting response data from your spring controller?

Comment: I am getting whole jsp page as response from spring controller

Comment: whole JSP as a response,what does it mean? i was asking about the data in response,are you getting from your controller, what you are getting in alert box inside success fucntion??

Comment: In alert box inside the success function whole JSP file is been displayed... that's why i told that response is jsp file not a hash map.. Please help me.. thanks in advance

Comment: just modified the method inside controller(use above code),i was thinking in different way,can you check now what you are getting in response inside the alert fucntion?

Comment: I am getting error inside alert function.. Control is not entering succes function.

Comment: I said ,i just have modified my answer, now method return type is no more ModelView but HashMap itself,you can see in above answer section    ------>>>>@RequestMapping(value = "/getstates", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody HashMap<String, String>  showstates(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "") 
    String country,@Valid    @ModelAttribute("employee")Login employee, 
    BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {  
    HashMap<String,String>  stateMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    //put your logic to add state on basis of country

    return stateMap;
    }

Comment: can you now just test this and let me know the data you are getting in  alert inside success function?

Comment: i modified the code as u said but now control s not moving inside success function.. Error is dispalyed in alert function. I mean its going to error function instead of succes function

Answer (score 0):

shearing my solution. because i was stuck in same condition.

html page

```js
$(document).ready(function() { // for client name 

  $('#example').change(function(event) {
   var country = $("select#example").val(); // country = define value of selected option
   $.getJSON('ajaxAction0', {
    ptype : country
   }, function(data) {
    var select = $('#clientname');
    select.find('option').remove();
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
     $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo(select);
    });
   });
  });
 });
```

```html
<div>
  <select class="form-control" name="example" id="example">
   <option value="0">ALL</option>
   <option th:each="dropdown : ${dropdown}" th:value="${dropdown.id}"
    th:text="${dropdown.tagName}"></option>
  </select> <select class="form-control" name="clientname" id="clientname">
   <option value="0">ALL</option>
   <option th:each="dropd : ${drpdwn}" th:value="${dropd.id}"
    th:text="${dropd.tagName}"></option>
  </select>
  <button id="w-button-search" type="button">Search</button>
 </div>
```

**controller code for first drop down**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dropdown", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String dropDown(Model model) {
    List<Tag> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add(new Tag(1, "ruby"));
    data.add(new Tag(2, "rails"));
    data.add(new Tag(3, "c / c++"));
    data.add(new Tag(4, ".net"));
    data.add(new Tag(5, "python"));
    data.add(new Tag(6, "java"));
    data.add(new Tag(7, "javascript"));
    data.add(new Tag(8, "jscript"));
    model.addAttribute("dropdown", data);
    return "dropDown";
}
```

**second drop down code is**

```
Map <\string, string> udata = null;
@RequestMapping(value = "ajaxAction0", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> findAllAgencies(
        @RequestParam(value = "ptype", required = true) String ptype) {
    udata = new HashMap<>();
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    List<UserRecord> user = em
            .createNativeQuery("Select id, name, email from user_Record where id = :uid", UserRecord.class)
            .setParameter("uid", ptype).getResultList();
            for(UserRecord ur:user)     {
        udata.put(ur.getEmail(), ur.getName());
    }
    return udata;   }
```

hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a list of states based on the country:

```
@Autowired
StateService stateService;

@GetMapping("/states")
public @ResponseBody List<State> getStates(@RequestParam String country) {
    return stateService.getStates(country) ;
}
```

your State class will contain code and name;

```
$("select#country").change(function() {
    var countryVal = $("#country").val();
    $.ajax({
       url : '/states?country='+countryVal,
       method : 'GET',
    },
    success: function (states) {
        var stateSelect = $('#state'); // the state select element
        stateSelect.find('option').remove();
        for (i = 0; i < states.length; i++) { 
            stateSelect.append("<option value=" + states[i].code + " >" + states[i].name + "</option>")
        }
    },

    error :function()
    {
       alert("error");
    }          

});
```